# Downvote for no reason

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

I am not sure this is an appropriate question or not. It looks like I'm being 'targeted' by someone on Math S.E. I got so many downvotes today (yesterday I got 1 downvote) for no reason and no one admitted it. I can accept it if I get downvotes because my answers or questions are really bad but they seem fine to me, nothing is wrong with those yet I still get downvotes. It's really frustrating me.

[image]

Is kind of behavior permitted here?

---

**ADDITION**

[image]

As you can see in the printscreen picture above, I got serial downvotes **again** two days ago. Luckily, I did not get online on that day so it did not give me a bad mood and also the reputation has been reversed. Does the user who did this to me get a punishment or at least a warning from the moderators because of his/her action? I am quite sure (s)he is an adult user but how come (s)he did this to kid like me? In my opinion, what (s)he did to me is really unacceptable and gives a bad role model. It also changes my viewpoint to adult users here.

Comment: Mr. @AsafKaragila, I really want some discussion but ... Never mind, you can close my question. It's really a bad day for me. Good night.

Comment: I'm sorry that you are having a bad day. Serial voting gets reversed the next day. If not, you should flag for the moderators. There's really nothing we can do, and there's no real point to discuss this. But if it makes you feel any better, it happened to a lot of people, more than once, so most people can identify with your feeling.

Comment: 7 downvotes are continues, within 1 min.  Tomorrow this will be reverted and perhaps the troll who did this will be issued a warning by the mods. Personally I don't like the SE's feature to allow downvoting without leaving comment. Secondly downvoting on a question doesn't cost any rep to the downvoter, in contrast to downvote an answer, which costs -1 rep. Again I don't this feature too. I had faced this same thing(on some other SE site) once in past and it was reverted the next day. Don't take it personally. Your posts are ok.

Comment: When I'll be free I will read your posts thoroughly and will upvote if I find them useful.

Comment: @user31782: There are users (both on math.SE and throughout the SE network) who _do_ "revenge downvote" when they _think_ they know who has downvoted their posts (even if the original downvoting is not serial). Requiring comments to go alongside downvotes would perhaps be a cure worse than the disease.

Comment: @user31782 Thanks. I'm still learning here so I hope you be nice to me $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @ArthurFischer What is wrong with my title on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/815863/133248)? Why Mr. Integrals keep editing the title. It's really annoying me. I just wanna sleep right now but he keeps bother me. I'm so scare of him. Could you please do something Sir?

Comment: @V-Moy Probably because the title "Monster Integral" is unhelpful. Casual descriptors aren't generally appreciated; what's difficult for one person may not be for another, etc. Helpful titles describe what the problem is. If I see something like "Monster Integral" I'm thinking either it's something related to the Monster group (which your question appears not to be), or I am thinking it's a poorly-titled question. That said, repeat editing is annoying, and it's best for editors/posters to use comments to clarify and communicate.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Requiring comments along with downvotes won't become a disease. How would one downvote serialy without giving appropriate reason? Infact it will make the downvoting system more constructive. Downvoting a post without giving a slightest hint lays the OP only wondering; OP never knows what is wrong and how he/she could improve.

Comment: @user31782: This has been discussed ad nauseam on meta (and I'm sure most meta sites on the SE network). What if there are ten people downvoting? Each has to write a comment? And if all users downvote for the same reason, do nine of them write "Me too" or something? That's nonsense. What if I write a completely non-constructive comment, like a joke or whatever? What if I later delete that comment? Why aren't upvotes explained too, since sometimes they really do seem arbitrary (even more than downvotes in most cases)?

Comment: Mr. @Arkamis How about Freshman's dream, Sophomore's dream, and sandwich theorem? Are those also poorly-titled? When I heard for the first time about those things, I thought they were college stuff or kind of food.

Comment: Those are widely accepted names, recognized by many. On the other hand, "monster integral" means something you to you.

Comment: Mr. @AsafKaragila I think S.E. should have peer reviewing on the answer that has been downvoted like peer reviewing on the question that has been edited by other users.

Comment: @V-Moy: Perhaps having a review queue for posts with score below a certain level is a good idea, but maybe not. It should also be noted that edits are not reviewed by others once the editor has sufficient reputation, so your analogy doesn't hold water.

Comment: @Arkamis But those are not widely accepted yet when they introduced for the first time. Similarly with gravity & relativity theory on physics.

Comment: The difference is that those things are very interesting, widely applicable, and/or frequently used. Your integral, I might say, is none of those things. It's slightly complicated at best, not something likely to appear often, and it's solution offers very little in the way of new insight.

Comment: Compare that to the Monster group, the enumeration of which took many of the best mathematicians in the field many years to complete, a task which substantially contributed to the completion of a remarkable result in group theory. That kind of thing gets its own cutesy name.

Comment: @Arkamis How about [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/492208/133248). It has been 8 month here but no one edits the title. So why does someone give so many cares about my title?

Comment: Mr. @AsafKaragila I think we can make a special rule for peer reviewing on the downvoted answer

Comment: @V-Moy Eight months ago, perhaps we were not as vigilant. And editing it now would only serve to resurrect an old post, and is pointless. Past oversights are not a justification for present actions... just ask the government!

Comment: Arrggghhhh!? It's not fair!! It's even not a school but why there are so many rules?? I thought I can have fun while I'm learning here ᕙ(｀皿´)╯

Comment: V-Moy, the society that you live in and interact with on a daily basis has way more rules. Most of which are unwritten. It takes time to learn and accumulate these rules in mind. Does that mean that you can't have fun living? Some people might agree, but I think that most people will disagree.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  [_And if all users downvote for the same reason, do nine of them write "Me too" or something] Yes that would be a constructive feature -- OP will know that 9 users find his post bad for the same reason. [ "if I write a completely non-constructive comment, like a joke or whatever? What if I later delete that comment?"] This is a valid point. The whole voting system is faulty. It should be like whenever one would downvote he/she have to choose(click on) one of the reasons out of 1. Technically incorrect, 2. shows 0 research, 3. unclear, 4 Not useful. [cont]

Comment: ...[cont] after this the reasons will become somehow visible. this way no one will have to leave a comment and the OP will know why his/her post was downvoted and he/she will improve it. How constructive this would be!!

Comment: @user31782: I agree that adding a refinement to the voting is possibly useful; I disagree with removing the anonymity, though. And what about lying? I can downvote all your posts and say that they are clear or not useful. How is that helpful? More so if I do all that in the span of 10 minutes. How was that helpful? How it was helpful to you to know that I am the one downvoting you? Are you planning on revenge soon? Are you planning not to vote my posts anymore? Should that matter? If not, then votes should remain anonymous; as for feedback, it's easy to lie.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't say to remove the anonymity. What I mean is that if someone finds it time waste to write a comment for his/her downvote then there should be a shortcut through which the downvoter could explain the reason. About lying -- Then our new voting system is perfect to encounter this. Mods will easily know that the downvoter is vandalizing. I beleive most of the people do not lie, who downvote silently. They downvote silently because of the fear of revenge downvotes and time waste in writing. But if the OP could know the reason of their downvote then OP could improve the things.

Comment: @AsafKaragila About mentioning reason for an upvote -- This will also be a constructive feature. On [physics.overflow](http://physicsoverflow.org/activity/refereeing) they have two options for upvoting for review research paper(a type of question). BUT that's a totally different case. General question are upvoted usually as we do here. Though, having multiple options to upvote will be a good constructive feature. One will know that this question is upvoted due to research effort and that question is upvoted due to popularity and so and so.

Comment: Mr. @Arkamis Okay, let say my question poorly-titled. How about user Integrals that gives his questions with titles like these: Fun Integral, Cool Integral, Marvelous Integral, Short & Sweet Integral, Interesting, FunFun, Lovely Integral, Pie Integral, etc?

Comment: Those titles are also terrible. The existence of other bad titles isn't a free pass to not attempt better title-writing. Editing and review on this site is not comprehensive. Your bad title got caught; others' didn't. Deal with it.

Comment: @Arkamis I don't mind to edit them all. I'll do it with a very great pleasure. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: So, there's another serial downvoting. One thing is sure the downvoter is a noob and is quite unfamilar with SE system. When I had serial downvoting -- after it was was reverted the downvoter downvoted most of my posts with a gap of 1-day. There are really some a!@#ole people in this world.

Comment: Do you know how I've gotten rid of those silly downvoters. I changed my profile name, avatar etc. When I asked on meta for the reason of downvotes on my posts I got more downvotes. All this voting and reputation system is mundane. Now I do not waste my time on SE in writing answers. One can learn far better by self-study than by wasting time here. cya.

Comment: Mr. @AsafKaragila: I edit my question. Do you mind giving some opinions as a senior member here? Thank you.

Comment: Mr. @ArthurFischer: I edit my question. Do you mind giving some opinions as a senior member and moderator here? Thank you.

Comment: Whether or not the downvoter gets a warning from the moderators, I do not know, perhaps Arthur can shed some light on this. However, regarding to "adult users", note that there are many people here which are not adults (legally, physically or mentally), and there is a known phenomenon that the internet can cause, sometimes, people to digress to being immature (especially under the guise of anonymity). If you want to do the mature thing, don't worry about it very much. If you feel there is a pattern voting against you, you can raise a flag for the mods or send an email to the community managers

Comment: @V-Moy if it is a second serial downvote, the proper way is flag the question for mods. If this keep on a few more times, then escalate to the community managers. (Keep the record and evidences).

Comment: Mr. @AsafKaragila There are too many downvotes. Is there another way, a simple one? Besides, the system has reversed my rep. Should I still raise the flags?

Comment: Mr. @achillehui: There are too many downvotes. Is there another way, a simple one? Besides, the system has reversed my rep. Should I still raise the flags?

Comment: @V-Moy, you only need to raise the flags on one question and mention approximately how many question are affected. The point is notify the "group" of mods (instead of individual mod) something has happened. After the system has reversed your rep, whether you raise the flags or not is up to you.

Comment: @V-Moy: If that happens for a third time, I'd raise a flag. For twice, well, as achille hui said, it's up to you.

Comment: Mr. @AsafKaragila and Mr. achillehui Because my reps is back, for now I can forgive the user who did this to me but for the next time, I'll raise the flags to notify the mods like your suggestion. Thank you. (ô‿ô)